# Use Multiple Middleware for Combined Routes in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I'm going to assign all routes to Admin role, a few routes to operation role and a few routes to other roles in my App. I've tried to use group middleware in Laravel 8.

The code for Admin Role alone works fine. But, when I add middleware to other roles in the route group, it's not functioned how I expected.

**My code:**

**Web.php:**

```
    Route::middleware(['role:Admin'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return redirect('/home');
        });
     
        Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
        
        Route::get('/employee_register', [App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeRegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('employee_register');
        
        Route::post('/employee_register', [App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeRegisterController::class, 'save'])->name('employee_save');
        
        Route::post('/DoAsync', [App\Http\Controllers\AjaxController::class,'ajaxTask'])->middleware('only.ajax');
        
        Route::get('/job_booking', [App\Http\Controllers\JobBookingController::class, 'index'])->name('job_booking');
        
        Route::post('/DoAsync_jb', [App\Http\Controllers\JobBookingAjaxController::class,'ajaxTask'])->middleware('only.ajax');
        
        Route::post('/DoAsync_ai', [App\Http\Controllers\AssignInchargeAjaxController::class,'ajaxTask'])->middleware('only.ajax');
        
    });

    
Route::middleware(['role:operation'])->group(function () {
        
        Route::get('/', function () {
        
            return redirect('/job_booking');
        
        });
     
        
        Route::get('/home', function(){
        
            return redirect('/job_booking');
    
        })->name('home');
        
        
        Route::get('/job_booking', [App\Http\Controllers\JobBookingController::class, 'index'])->name('job_booking');
        
        Route::post('/DoAsync_jb', [App\Http\Controllers\JobBookingAjaxController::class,'ajaxTask'])->middleware('only.ajax');
        
        Route::post('/DoAsync_ai', [App\Http\Controllers\AssignInchargeAjaxController::class,'ajaxTask'])->middleware('only.ajax');
        
    });
```

**The Middleware**
(EnsureUserHasRole):

```
class EnsureUserHasRole
    {
        
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string $role)
        {
            
            //I received Call to a member function roles() on null error when accessing login and logout. 
            // So, I used this to avoid role check on login & logout routes.
            
            if ( $request->route()->named('login') || $request->route()->named('logout') ) {
                
                return $next($request);
    
            }
            
             
            elseif ($request->user()->roles()->where('role', '=', $role)->exists()) {
    
                return $next($request);
    
            }
                    
            abort(403);
    
        }
    
    }
```

**Models:**

**User:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    
    protected $fillable = [
        'employee_id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
    }
    
}
```

**Role:**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user');
    }
    
}
```

Without the second Middleware (`middleware(['role:operation'])`), all routes would be accessed. But, then adding it, the `if` condition in `EnsureUserHasRole` middleware executes the `abort(403)`

Should I use any `if` in the middleware in `web.php`?

Note: `middleware('only.ajax')` has been used to ensure the controller is accessed only on Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the routes. If you run `php artisan route:list` you will notice that half of your routes are missing.

Lets take an example route `'/'`, what you did is similar to this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
})->middleware(['role:Admin']);

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/job_booking');
})->middleware(['role:operation']);
```

As you can see routes duplicates.

To avoid this you need to add prefix to your routes like:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
})->middleware(['role:Admin']);

Route::get('/operation', function () {
    return redirect('/job_booking');
})->middleware(['role:operation']);
```

Check out [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) for more information.

Comment: To explain further, there is a direct 1:1 relationship between routes and the controller function they call. The middleware isn't used as a conditional because a user could be both operation and Admin roles, and Laravel won't know where to send them. Some more logic is needed to route by role.